# Nginx routing issue

Tags: nginx

Not entirely sure how to ask this but I have also looked all over the web and couldn't find an answer so any help is much appreciated.

I'm trying to set up an API call through my site that uses nginx, if I send the url /api/timestamp/ it works just fine and returns what is intended. However if i add a parameter and send /api/timestamp/2015-08-09 it tries to open the file 2015-08-09 which obviously doesn't exist.

How do I get Nginx to pass the parameter as an argument to my program and not try to use it as a route? Or am I looking at this all wrong?

```
server {
    listen          83 default_server;
    server_name     portfolio.com;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/port.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/port.error.log;
    root            /var/www/portfolio/;
    index           index.php;

    error_page 404    /404.html;
    error_page 405    =200 $uri;

    location /api/timestamp/ {

            rewrite         /api/timestamp/(.*) /api/timestamp/?param=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files       $uri $uri/  =404;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

}

Comment: Does this not go in server fault?

Answer (score 0):

you need use a rewrite rule, the most simple solution for you is some like this

```
location /api/timestamp/ {
    rewrite /api/timestamp/(.*) /api/timestamp/?param=$1 last;
}
```

Then you will receive the value in  a parameter named **param** (change it according your requeriments).

Obviously, you can use a regex most restrictive to avoid undesired values .

You can get more information in https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, I've attatched the rest of the file as I'm now getting a 500 error, which the logs say is due to a rewrite or internal redirection cycle. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please change the rewrite rule like: rewrite ^/api/timestamp/(.*)$ /api/timestamp/?param=$1 last;